# How can I compare Multiply columns in Python based on conditions set?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

Need assistance into how I can parse through a dataset in Python to create a new column once certain conditions are met.

I have a dataset containing a list of accounts where I need to check if there is any discrepancies with regard to interest rates applied. Below is a made up sample to portray what I am trying to do, as I cannot disclose the real data for obvious reasons .

[View Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IRZg.jpg)

Column A "**Account**" is the unique bank account, which are linked to Level1, Level1 is then linked to Level2 and Level 2 is linked up to the ultimate parent at level3.

The Credit Rate, Credit Code, Debit Code and Debit Rate (all independent of each other) should match **level 2** and its **Currency**. If the interest rate conditions all match level2 by currency all accounts are setup correctly and reporting the correct rates, those that don't match would be deemed exception and would require further investigation.

Comment: Hi. Please see this article on how to write a good question. Post data, rather than images as well, and show any code you've tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Understood Jonathan, makes sense.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.